# Using GRID and PACK in the same GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been looking around slack and lots of people saying it is possible but no examples of how to do it.

I'm looking to use both pack and grid within the same GUI. I have setup 2 different frames 1 using pack the other grid but I still get an error when trying to run the GUI.

I was under the impression you could use the different commands as long as there were in different frames?

here is my code

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
root.title("UKIND Industry Tool")
root.geometry("600x600")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

# ----- Top Frame -----
topFrame = Frame(root, bg="grey", width=600, height=25, pady=1)
topFrame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

# ----- Top Frame Label -----

oreCalc = Button(topFrame, text= "Ore Calculator")
minCalc = Button(topFrame, text= "Mineral Calculator")
oreCalc.pack(side=LEFT)
#minCalc.pack(side=LEFT)

# ----- Bottom Frame -----

bottomFrame = Frame(root, bg="green", width=600, height=585, pady=1)
bottomFrame.grid()


root.mainloop()
```

And here is the trace back error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Ganjena/Desktop/Course/Projects/helloworld/test.py", line 22, in 
>       bottomFrame.grid()
>     File "C:\Users\Ganjena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 2220, in grid_configure
>       + self._options(cnf, kw))
>   _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 3):

Both `topFrame` and `bottomFrame` are children of your root window, but you called `.pack()` on one, and `.grid()` on the other.  In other words, THE ERROR MESSAGE MEANS EXACTLY WHAT IT SAYS!

What you can actually do is use `.grid()` on children of `bottomFrame`; that doesn't conflict with the use of `.pack()` on the children of `topFrame`, or on `bottomFrame` itself.  But any two widgets that share a parent must share a geometry manager.